# Hyper-V avhd files compressed

Tags: hyper-v, compression, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have inherited a machine at a client site that the previous IT person thought it would be a bright idea to compress all the AVHD and the base VHD files for one of their servers running under hyper-v on a 2008 R2 host.  I have 4 of the 6 files uncompressed, but I get an error message saying "An error occurred applying attributes to the file: "SBS.avhd file" The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation.

I can't boot the machine with the files compressed, can anyone please shed some light on this and how I can get it uncompressed? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Try copying the files to an uncompressed folder. The copies should then be uncompressed. You can then delete the source files and copy or  move the uncompressed files back to the original location.

Comment: Copying right now to a nas that is onsite...I'll update in about 6 hrs when it is estimated to be completed.  Thanks for the reply joeqwerty!

Comment: Do you have enough free disk space on the Hyper-V host to copy them to a local folder?

Comment: i might for one of them, thats the other twist to this that is making life miserable...resources are limited.

Comment: Well I dont know if copying those files worked yet, they have a lock on them and the permissions are different.  Pressing on...

Comment: Right, because you copied them to a different system with different permissions. When you copy them back to their original location they should inherit the permissions of their parent folder on the original system.

Comment: As an aside, make sure to document the configuration of the VM's that these VHD's belong to. Worst case scenario would be to create new VM's using these VHD's.